# Email customer when programmatically creating invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice

While creating an invoice programmatically, how can I make the system email the invoice to the customer?

```
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid); 
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
    Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without products.'));
}
$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_ONLINE);
$invoice->register();
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                   ->addObject($invoice)
                   ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());
$transactionSave->save();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After `$transactionSave->save();`:

```
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$history = $invoice->getOrder()->addStatusHistoryComment(
    'Programmatically created invoice', true
);
$invoice->sendEmail(true, '');
$order->save();
```

This will instruct Magento to email the invoice to the customer.

Comment: is the set status is necessary for sending the email?

Comment: Yes, this is a Magento norm. If not included, the order will not be set to Processing (which it should be once invoiced).